# Why is the text being cut off from this combobox?

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

Here's a screen shot of the problem:

[image]

As you can see the left-most part of the string is getting truncated. This is just a standard combobox and there's nothing overlapping it on the form.

Comment: looks like your `Label` is too wide

Comment: Jeez. It WAS the label... but it doesn't look like it's overlapping in the designer! Sorry.

Answer (score 7):

Your label is too long!

its overwriting the edge of that edit box.

Answer (score 2):

Bring the combobox to the front. It seems like the label before your combobox is in front of it.

Answer (score -1):

Just reproduced this.

As previous comments suggest, your label is most definitely too long.

Please reconsider the placement of your elements, perhaps the label should end with more space between the label and the combobox.

This can easily be done via the designer window (Shift + F7 whilst on the code behind e.g. form.cs)